# What algorithm is used for forecasting in Azure Data Explorer?

Tags: time-series, azure-data-explorer

What algorithm is used in `series_decompose_forecast()` function for predicting future values? Is it possible to change the algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/series-decompose-forecastfunction), it's seasonal decomposition. There are few parameters to tweak the algorithm (all documented). If you want a totally different algorithm you can build it from more native functions like series_outliers, series_periods_detect etc., or import inline a Python/R code

Comment: Is it possible to get more details on how the decomposition is done under the hood?

Comment: It is described in describe in the doc, see the paragraph titled "More about series decomposition" and follow the link to time series decomposition chapter https://otexts.com/fpp2/decomposition.html

Comment: thanks. However i was looking something more specific and detailed, in that reference several versions of the decomposition are presented, and none with great detail.